# HYPERLINK - Reference a cell containing named range

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, named-ranges

I have a recipe book spreadsheet with a navigation bar to different categories (ex. PREP or HOT etc.).  When Selecting PREP, a second list appears with all of the prep items.  The user clicks on the PREP item and the recipe appears. I CAN MAKE ALL OF THIS WORK.  But it's a little clunky as I'm using hidden cells to manage which recipe list is showing.

What I want to do, is have one list update based on the category, by referencing a named range stored in a cell.

EXAMPLE:

```
=HYPERLINK("#PREP_1",E2)
```

This works perfect.

But when I have "#PREP_1" stored in A1

```
=HYPERLINK(INDIRECT(A1),E2)
```

This does not work.  I have tried many iterations but can't seem to find a work around.

Am I just being dumb?  ....probably shouldn't ask that in the internet!

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your use case but wouldn't this work as is `=HYPERLINK(A1,E2)`? I think the problem is HYPERLINK expects a text string and not a reference. Also try =HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDIRECT(A1)),"Go to the reference inside A1")

Comment: Worst case you might have to do `=CHOOSE(MATCH(A1, {"prep1","prep2","prep3"}, 0), HYPERLINK("prep1"), HYPERLINK("prep2"), HYPERLINK("prep3"))`

Comment: =HYPERLINK(A1,E2) not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple difficulties here. One is that `INDIRECT()` is not needed. And that is because of the second difficulty:  you are giving `HYPERLINK()` a string, not a reference of some sort. A string is demanded, not a reference, and `HYPERLINK()` will do the work of treating it as a reference when it does its own magic. Converting it to a reference actually gives the function a parameter it cannot use. And then there's one more difficulty:

`#PREP_1` is not a valid name for a Named Range. You are using `INDIRECT()` to get the value in A1 and turn it into a reference. Good so far, except that what is IN A1 must be a valid reference or it cannot do that step.

The problem with `#PREP_1` is that leading `#`. So if you separate it from the rest of it (the rest being an acceptable name to Excel), things will go fine:

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&A1,E2)
```

Actually, since you will separate the pieces and use them as pieces of text to build a string, you don't need (and never did need) `INDIRECT()`. As shown above, Excel finds the value in A1, then appends it to the `#` getting `#PREP_1`, a string, which it is expecting and happy to use immediately, no further work needed.

Mind you that `PREP_1` must still be a Named Range or the string will not resolve to anything `HYPERLINK()` can work with and it will give an error.

Usually, problems people face with `INDIRECT()` and Named Ranges is they forget they've inserted a level to resolve and have not changed the formula to do so, or to take a level away thereby staying even keel. But in this case, you are adding a level of resolution so that the formula resolves it to a workable value (if that value were presented differently that is) and then resolves that value to a nothing, so to speak, and Excel doesn't know what to do with the nothing it ends up as.

Answer (score -1):

Oh man, I tried every iteration I could think of in A1 EXCEPT removing #.  I got it to work with VALUETOTEXT(A1) as the reference, but leaving A1 as just the Named Range and adding the # in Hyperlink is so much easier.

Simply:

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&A1,E2)
```

Is all it took!

THANK YOU!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).